# Make column with "sample" for each row with purrr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to make column with sample value for each row of data 
But I'm new with `purrr` and can't make this.
My code

```
df<-data.frame(x=rep(1:3,each=4),y=99)
df%>%
  group_by(x)%>%
  mutate_(val=~purrr::map_dbl(function(x) sample(50,1)))
```

This didn't work.

 But function with `purrr` only working:

```
1:5%>%purrr::map_dbl(function(x) sample(50,1))
[1] 39 30  7 18 45
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to use `purrr`, I guess you could do:

```
dplyr::mutate(df, val = purrr::map(x, ~ sample(50, 1)))
```

> ```
>    x  y val
> 1  1 99  35
> 2  1 99   4
> 3  1 99  43
> 4  1 99  28
> 5  2 99  49
> 6  2 99  31
> 7  2 99  31
> 8  2 99  31
> 9  3 99  19
> 10 3 99   4
> 11 3 99  43
> 12 3 99  20
> ```

Or with the pipe:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  mutate(val = map(x, ~ sample(50, 1)))
```

---

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:3, each = 4), y = 99)
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need purrr:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:3, each = 4), y = 99)

df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(val = sample(50, n()))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   x [3]
       x     y   val
   <int> <dbl> <int>
 1     1  99.0    10
 2     1  99.0    25
 3     1  99.0     2
 4     1  99.0    24
 5     2  99.0    48
 6     2  99.0    19
 7     2  99.0    34
 8     2  99.0    33
 9     3  99.0    24
10     3  99.0    14
11     3  99.0    37
12     3  99.0    12
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, but if you can, then I need an answer with `purrr` foк similar tasks. thx

Comment: Why? `purrr` is a functional programming package. Nothing here requires that. Update your post with an example that can't be solved without `purrr`